# ExceptionInInitializerError - Class not compiled

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Below is the error I am getting from the netbeans IDE when I run my server. as the error says

> Uncompilable source code - Projects.ApplicationMenu is not abstract
>   and does not override abstract method setProject(Projects.Project) in
>   Projects.AbstractComponent

but there are no errors. I checked the Menu superclass and it does override the abstract method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at Projects.Project.initialize(Project.java:54)
at Projects.Project.<init>(Project.java:34)
at Server.FileIO.ProjectIO.ProjectIO.translate(ProjectIO.java:52)
at Server.FileIO.ProjectService.LoadProjects(ProjectService.java:55)
at Server.FileIO.ProjectService.<init>(ProjectService.java:42)
at Server.FileIO.FileService.<init>(FileService.java:35)
at Server.ServerInitialization.InitializeModelAndProjects(ServerInitialization.java:47)
at Server.Server.Initialize(Server.java:97)
at Server.Server.<init>(Server.java:46)
at Server.Server.main(Server.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Projects.ApplicationMenu is not abstract and does not override abstract method setProject(Projects.Project) in Projects.AbstractComponent
at Projects.UIComponent.<clinit>(UIComponent.java:15)
... 10 more
```

Below is the ApplicationMenu class:

```
package Projects;

import Key.Key;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

/**
 *
 * @author Mark
 */
public class ApplicationMenu extends Menu{
    MenuBar menubar;
    ApplicationMenu parentmenu;

    public ApplicationMenu(String name, MenuBar menubar, Key key) {
        super(name, null, key, menubar.project);
        this.menubar = menubar;
    }
    public ApplicationMenu(String name, ApplicationMenu parentmenu, Key key){
        super(name, parentmenu, key, parentmenu.project);
    }
    public ApplicationMenu(JsonObject jsonApplicationMenu, String name, MenuBar menubar, Key key){
        super(name, null, key, menubar.project);
        this.menubar = menubar;
        this.unPackComponent();
    }
    public ApplicationMenu addApplicationMenu(String name, Key key){
        ApplicationMenu menu = new ApplicationMenu(name, this, key);
        this.addChildMenu(menu);
        return menu;
    }
    public ComponentMenu addComponentMenu(String name, Key key){
        ComponentMenu menu = new ComponentMenu(name, this, key);
        this.addChildMenu(menu);
        return menu;
    }
    @Override
    public JsonObject packComponent(){
        JsonArrayBuilder arraybuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        this.childmenus.forEach((cmkey,menu)->{
            arraybuilder.add(menu.packComponent());
        });
        packagedJsonArray = arraybuilder.build();
        packagedJsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add(Menu.childMenus(), packagedJsonArray)
                                    .add( Menu.menuType(), ApplicationMenu.applicationMenu())
                                    .add(AbstractComponent.name(), this.name)
                                    .add(Key.key(),this.packKey()).build();
        return packagedJsonObject;
    }
    public final static String applicationMenu(){return "ApplicationMenu";}

    @Override
    public final void unPackComponent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    void translateFromHeFile() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Below is the Menu superclass of ApplicationMenu:

```
package Projects;

import Key.Key;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Mark
 */
public abstract class Menu extends UIComponent{
    Menu parentMenu;
    HashMap<Key, Menu> childmenus;

    public Menu(String name, Menu parentMenu, Key key, Project project) {
        super(name, parentMenu, key);
        this.parentMenu = parentMenu;
        childmenus = new HashMap<>();//
        this.project = project;
    }
    public Menu addChildMenu(Menu menu){
        childmenus.put(menu.key, menu);
        return menu;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    @Override
    protected void setProject(Project project){
        this.project = project;
    }
    @Override
    public Project getProject(){
        return this.project;
    }
    public final static String childMenus(){return "ChildMenus";}
    public final static String menuType(){return "MenuType";}
}
```

As you can see I do override that method. I have tried restarting the IDE several times. I have also tried clean and build of all my dependant projects several times. One thing that I did was move a package between projects. I realized I could not move this package to the common project due to certain dependencies. After I moved it back I started getting this error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Below is the AbstractComponent class:

```
package Projects;

import Key.Key;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

/**
 *
 * @author Mark
 */
public abstract class AbstractComponent implements Component {
    String name;
    Key key;
    AbstractComponent parentComponent;
    HashMap<Key, AbstractComponent> childComponents;
    JsonObject packagedJsonObject;
    JsonArray packagedJsonArray;
    Project project;

    public AbstractComponent( String name, AbstractComponent parentComponent, Key key){
        this.name = name;
        this.parentComponent = parentComponent;
        this.key = key;
        childComponents = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public AbstractComponent addChild(AbstractComponent projectelement){
        childComponents.put(projectelement.key, projectelement);
        return projectelement;
    }
    @Override
    public Key getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }
    public JsonObject packKey(){
        return this.key.toJsonObject();
    }
    abstract JsonObject packComponent();
    abstract void unPackComponent();
    abstract void translateFromHeFile();
    abstract protected void setProject(Project project);
    public final static String name(){return "Name";}
}
```

Comment: `setProject` should be public not protected, no?

Comment: Sorry it should be protected. I did not post the abstract class. I just edited my question to include that class as well.

Comment: but what if you make it public? What happens to the error then?

Comment: I had to change 15 classes. However, that worked. When I changed it, I no longer got the error. Any reason why? I did not have any errors the other way. If you could explain why please post this as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks Again!

Comment: I'm betting that Component is found in another package, and you can't access the protected method or method signature from a different package. You're only finding out when you try to create a concrete class since abstract classes will work fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually all classes are in the same package. Solution still stands though. The IDE catches the problem you explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the setProject method originates in an interface or parent class declared in another package, perhaps the Component interface. If so, then your abstract classes will compile fine, but a concrete class will fail once you try to override a protected method that was declared in a different package.

If so, the solution is to make setProject public.